# empty mysqldump file with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to backup a database using the PHP system command and mysqldump.exe. I have specified the absolute path to mysqldump.exe, followed by various options.

This is how I am currently making the call -

```
$path = "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\ABCD\mysqldump.exe";
$command = $path." <dump options>" > <backup filename> ";
system($command);
```

This is generating a sql file with absolutely no contents. I figured the problem is because of the spaces in the path name, because

```
$path = "C:\ABCD\mysqldump.exe";
$command = $path." <dump options>" > <backup filename> ";
system($command);
```

works absolutely fine.

I am unable to figure out how to make things work when the path contains spaces. I checked other threads which talked about escapeshellarg, etc but using that on the path doesn't work either.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really doing this?

```
$system($command);
```

Should instead be:

```
// No $ on system()
system($command);
```

Also, try double backslashes for Windows paths:

```
$path = "\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\User\\Desktop\\ABCD\\mysqldump.exe\"";
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typing mistake. I am using system($command).
but will using double backslashes fix the space issue, because if there are no spaces, works fine.

Comment: The path would also need to be surrounded by quotes within the actual command. `"\"C:\\......mysqldump.exe\""`, otherwise the spaces will kill the command by trying to execute `C:\Documents`.

Comment: okay, thanks Michael and Marc, will try what both of you said.